# Expression of matrix

Tags: matrices

I am haunted by a question about matrix. I would like to express $E$ (whose dimension is $n \times n$) with $ A,B,C,D$ and $x'$ which are given:
$$ D\left[ Ax \space Bx \space Cx \right]^\text{T} x' = Ex$$ or

$$\left[ Ax \space Bx \space Cx \right]D x' = Ex$$
where:

$D$ is of dimension $n\times3$ (first equation) or $3\times n$ (second equation); $A,B,C$ are of dimension $n\times n$; $x$ and $x'$ are of dimension $n \times 1$;

$Ax$ , $Bx$ and $Cx$ become three columns of matrix  $\left[ Ax \space Bx \space Cx \right]$ whose dimension is $n \times 3$.

I tried matlab symbolic toolbox to get the expression, but the result is too complicated to extract a general expression. Thanks in advance for some help.

Comment: $Ax$, $Bx$ and $Cx$ all have dimension $n\times 1$, the product $(Ax) (Bx)$ is not defined

Comment: There is a problem of dimensionality there. You can't multiply $D$ by the other factor. Also, you can't multiply $AxBx$ and $BxCx$ either.

Comment: Sorry for missing the definition of $\left[ Ax \space Bx \space Cx \right]$.

Comment: @ZihanShen Quote:"$x$ and $x′$ are of dimension  $n\times 1$." They cannot have both the same dimension $n\times 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry for not defining the dimension of $E$ whose dimension is $n \times n$. Besides, the operations in the above equations are linear,  as far as I am concerned, there maybe a way to express the left side of equation with a product of $E$ and $x'$.

Comment: I think you're saying that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $x'$ are given and that you want to find $E$ such that your equation holds for every $n$ by 1 vector $x$, do I have that right?  If so, the first column of $E$ is found using $x=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]^T$, the second column is found using $x=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right]^T$, and the third column is found using $x=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]^T$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works very well. (I am still wandering if there is some way to a general expression.)